# How am I supposed to undergo diagnostics COVID-19 test within three days after entering South Korea?

Tags: covid-19, south-korea

I read on [website of the Embassy of the Republic of Korea in the USA](http://overseas.mofa.go.kr/us-en/brd/m_4500/view.do?seq=760989&srchFr=&srchTo=&srchWord=&srchTp=&multi_itm_seq=0&itm_seq_1=0&itm_seq_2=0&company_cd=&company_nm=&page=1) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201102015840/http://overseas.mofa.go.kr/us-en/brd/m_4500/view.do?seq=760989&srchFr=&srchTo=&srchWord=&srchTp=&multi_itm_seq=0&itm_seq_1=0&itm_seq_2=0&company_cd=&company_nm=&page=1)):

[image]

(sorry for the low resolution, that's the original resolution...)

How am I supposed to undergo diagnostics COVID-19 test within three days after entering South Korea given that I'm supposed to quarantine for 14 days? Does someone come to my place? Or do I have to go to a diagnostics facility, and if so, is there any restrictions on which means of transportation I can take to go there?

Comment: From expats groups on Facebook, you have to give your address for the quarantine when you arrive at the airport. They will tell you where to go at that time (no public transportation). I will check them later and make it an answer.

Comment: i am willing to bet you will get a pdf by mail and/or a piece of paper at the airport on arrival that explains this. I also predict you will be given a testing appointment and told to take a taxi (not public transit) to attend it. (That's what Singapore does and I expect Korea to be the same.)